# Write a function that returns the largest of the 4 numbers

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying to find the largest of four numbers with javascript and have been given the following code.

I was doing research on how to do this and they all are giving me options using arrays and don't have variables for numbers.

```
function largest(a, b, c, d){
    //Code goes here
}
let a = 10, b = 9, c = 11, d = 7;
//console.log(largest(a, b, c, d));
```

Comment: `const largest = Math.max`, done :P

Comment: @CertainPerformance - but `//Code goes here`!! :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have an iterable array in the function's `arguments`

```js
function largest(a, b, c, d){
   return Math.max.apply(null, arguments)
}
let a = 10, b = 9, c = 11, d = 7;

console.log(largest(a, b, c, d))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Math.max method

[MDN Math.max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)

```
let a = 10, b = 9, c = 11, d = 7;
let largest = Math.max(a, b, c, d); // 11
```

Answer (score 0):

Math.max() can compare multiple values and return the largest.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max

```
function largest(a, b, c, d){
    return Math.max(a, b, c, d)
}
let a = 10, b = 9, c = 11, d = 7;
console.log(largest(a, b, c, d));
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you want to shorten even more, use ES6 syntax:

```
const largest = (...nums) => Math.max(...nums);
let a = 10, b = 9, c = 11, d = 7;
console.log(largest(a, b, c, d));
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use `Math.max`:

```js
function largest(a, b, c, d) {
  return Math.max.apply(null, [a, b, c, d]);
}
console.log(largest(10, 9, 11, 7));
```

You can use `...` (rest/spread) to make it work for any number of arguments also:

```js
function largest(...nums) {
  return Math.max.apply(null, nums);
}
console.log(largest(1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 6, 5, 8, 1001));
```

You can even make it simpler by just assigning `largest` to `Math.max`:

```js
const largest = Math.max;
console.log(largest(1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 6, 5, 8, 10001));
```